# how to use multi pimage picker using Obx Getx in flutter and show in UI

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, imagepicker

what is the right way to use a multi-image picker using Getx OBX state management?
iam using Obx and the fileimage not showing the selected image.

Answer (score 0):

can you show your code here, maybe there is an error in debug. or you can see through the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8D0vBSQUAKY). I've followed the tutorial and it worked